# Search phone number in database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a phone record tables as

```
phones(id, number);

It may have values as:-
1, 9801234567
2, 980 1234568
3, 9779801234569
4, 9801234570
5, 977 980 1234 571
```

If someone search for 980 1234567 (with spaces), I can remove the spaces before running the queries to get the result.

But my problem is when someone search for 9779801234571 with a condition that there is no regular format of number, it must return the last record i.e. 977 980 1234 571. Any idea how to do it efficiently?

Comment: What happens if you normalize your data to always be free of spaces?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this:

```
 where replace(phonenumber, ' ', '') = replace($phonenumber, ' ', '')
```

Doing this efficiently is another matter.  For that, you would have to format your phone numbers in the database in a canonical format -- say by removing all the spaces in an `update` statement.  Then put the number you are searching for in the same format.  The query can then use an index on the column.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably best to **clean the phone numbers from whitespace before you write them into the database**. You can easily to this using this function:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Maybe you also have to strip out other characters like `-` or `/`.

Then you can use a simple `WHERE` condition without bells and whistles. This will also significantly improve the performance of your `SELECT` statement since you don't have to do conversions of your data in order to find the right row.

This is assuming that you fill the database yourself of course. If that's not the case, ignore this advise.

Comment: And what about phone numbers that look this way? 416–TAXICAB

Comment: Well, you could quite easily convert it to a number only phone number, too. Simply replace every letter with the number it represents.